# I made an extra Template Tag that's causing problems

Tags: python, html, django, frontend, backend

Guys I already made an init.py for this to make it a module so this cannot be the error

```
from django import template
from markdownx.utils import markdownify

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(name = 'markdown')
def markdown(text):
    return markdownify(text)
```

`<p>{{ blog.| markdown |safe }}</p>`
The above is not giving any error to me but when I write a blog, subsequently, on the webpage it is not showing anything, means for which I used markdown template tag, so please help me if you can.

Comment: Please check if it works without the dot after `blog`, e.g. `{{ blog|markdown|safe }}`. Maybe the error is because `blog.` is invalid syntax.

Comment: yes its worked, its a silly mistake, BTW thanks

Comment: No problem. I posted an answer for this below. Its unfortunate that Django doesn't throw a `TemplateSyntaxError` for this case.

Comment: Please consider [marking the answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it solved your problem, thanks!

Comment: sorry I forgetted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the syntax is incorrect with `{{ blog.|markdown|safe }}`.

Remove the `dot` and it should work: `{{ blog|markdown|safe }}`.